# Does data preprocessing with kreas.ImageDataGenerator create more data or just change the exsiting one

Tags: keras, generator

when using the keras.ImageDataGenerator, and choosing some augmentations (flip, zoom, etc.) does that **just change my datastream or** does it add augmented data to the data stream in addition, **increasing my data size**?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not increase your dataset as far as I know. It just adds random transforms or perturbations in your training data. So, yes, it just changes your data. Having said that, if you need more data

1. You can store augmented images using `save_to_dir` parameter
2. You can maybe use `steps_per_epoch = N*(n_samples / batch_size)` and train on `N` times the amount of data per epoch

Comment: Dear Anakin, first one I knew but the second tip sounds great as well. Thanks. MTFBWY